# Solving the constraint portion of the input-encoding problem

Tags: optimization, constraint-satisfaction, applied-theory, boolean-complexity

The "input-encoding problem" is where the binary representations of symbolic input variables to a Boolean function are chosen to minimize the decode logic complexity. The "Espresso-MV" software can be used to do this, [here's](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1270318) one of the most cited papers on the topic by the developer, from the mid-late 80s.

The relevant portion about how the input-encoding problem can be solved in practice:

[image]

I'm curious about how these constraint problems were solved "manually"? I know there's been significant research since then about computational solutions e.g.

https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/127601.127656

But as an example here's a test problem I input to Espresso-MV, representing a four-bit input (encoded as one-hot), and ten binary-valued output lines:

```
.mv 2 0 11 10
10000000000 | 1111111111
01000000000 | 1111111110
00100000000 | 1111111101
00010000000 | 1111111011
00001000000 | 1111110111
00000100000 | 1111101111
00000010000 | 1111011111
00000001000 | 1110111111
00000000100 | 1101111111
00000000010 | 1011111111
00000000001 | 0111111111
```

Espresso-MV then returns:

```
.mv 2 0 11 10
.p 6
00001000100 0101010010
01000110011 0011001010
00101101111 0000100101
11111100000 1111100000
10010011110 1000011011
11100011001 0110011100
.e
```

So I guess the ".p 6" line means a minimal encoding would allow 6 product terms in the output decoding structure if the constraints in the left-hand matrix can be solved, that is to say where there's a "1" in each row, those symbols have their binary representations all lying on the same face of a Boolean n-cube.

I could probably solve this on paper, diagrammatically, for encodings of two or three bits but for even just four bits I'm unsure how one would go about it systematically.